# How do I create a custom overlay container for angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, custom-overlay

I've tried to follow [this](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7349#issuecomment-337513040) guide.

I have a `OverlayContainer` subclass

```
import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

export class CdkOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {
  /**
  * Set the container element from the outside, e.g. from the corresponding directive
  */
  public setContainerElement(element: HTMLElement): void {
    this._containerElement = element;
  }
  /**
   * Prevent creation of the HTML element
   */
  protected _createContainer(): void {
    return;
  }
  
}
```

and then I have a directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkOverlayContainer } from './CdkOverlayContainer';
import {OverlayContainer} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myCdkOverlayContainer]'
})
export class CdkOverlayContainerDirective {

    constructor(protected renderer: Renderer2, protected elementReference: ElementRef, protected cdkOverlayContainer: OverlayContainer) {
       
        this.renderer.addClass(this.elementReference.nativeElement, 'cdk-overlay-container');
        (<any>this.cdkOverlayContainer).setContainerElement(this.elementReference.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
    { provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: CdkOverlayContainer },
```

Then I add a div with that directive

```
<div myCdkOverlayContainer>
  ...
</div>
```

to get the following error:

```
main.ts:14 TypeError: this.cdkOverlayContainer.setContainerElement is not a function
    at new CdkOverlayContainerDirective (CdkOverlayContainerDirective.ts:13)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.CdkOverlayContainerDirective_Factory [as factory] (CdkOverlayContainerDirective.ts:14)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was missing `Injectable`:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CdkOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {
...
```

Also @angular/cdk version did not match @angular version in package.json for some reason.